# Remove items on the basis of a class name on child element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the list of cars which shows both items 'Sold' and 'new' so I want to hide that car from list which have the label of 'sold' in Danish it is called "solgt" I used the following code with the help of jQuery but it disappear every car item in list including 'ny" as well here is the code

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  if ($('.slider-car-item:has(.Solgt)')) {
    //get checkbox not checked add class disable
    $('.slider-car-item').addClass('.dnone');
  } else {
    //remove class disabled
    $('.slider-car-item').removeClass('.dnone');
  }
  
});
```

```css
.dnone {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-car-item">
  <div>
   
      <article><span class="Solgt">SOLGT</span></article>
      <article><span class="ny">NY</span></article>
    
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Based on your example code, when will `slider-car-item` have the class `Solgt`? It looks like a child element gets that class. If that is the case you need to use `$(".slider-car-item .Solgt")` as the selector and not the `:has()`.

Comment: wherever the solgt class came inside li that list item should be hidden and else all should be displayed.

Comment: yeah my mistake its a class

Comment: So fix your question to say that. :) Also, I don't see any initially hidden items yet, per our conversation below.

Comment: i already fixed the html code and question can you please take a look of it

Answer (score 1):

Just select those elements which have the target class and find the closest ancestor list item. No need for all the logic.

Don't include dots in `addClass()`. Also, the second clause is pointless unless you'll ever have `.dnone` on an item at page load.

Alternatively, don't bother with a hide class. Just use jQuery's `hide()` method.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.slider-car-item li.dnone').removeClass('dnone');
  $('.Solgt').closest('li').addClass('dnone');
});
```

```css
.dnone {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-car-item">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><span class="Solgt">SOLGT</span></li>
      <li><span class="ny">NY</span></li>
      <li class="dnone"><span class="ny">NY (originally hidden)</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

write in way, and mostly I use 3.5+ jQuery so don't know if there are any difference but should be something like

```
$('.slider-car-item').find('.Solgt').fadeOut();
```

or

```
$('.slider-car-item').find('.Solgt').hide();
```

or

```
$('.slider-car-item').find('.Solgt').slideUp();
```

or

```
$('.slider-car-item').find('.Solgt').css('display', 'none');
```

or
$('.slider-car-item').find('.Solgt').addClass('dnone') ;

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list mistakes in your code

Comment: yeah that was part caused of be in way, few typos now should work

Comment: its make disabled the solgt class but there is multiple parent classes like it.. i actually want that whenever any parent class has this solgt class that specific parent class which includes this solgt whole parent class should be hidden!!

Comment: Then try like $('.Solgt').closest('.slider-car-item') and after dot 1 of above it action
Like $('.Solgt').closest('.slider-car-item').hide();

Comment: almost there.. but it also hide all the parent classes which have not '.Solgt' class as well